# Cant find my EF code first database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am doing Microsoft's MVC getting started tutorial:

[Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5.](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

This includes the creation of a code first database.

It all works fine, but I am not able to find my database.

This is my `ConnectionString`:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

If I debug my index Method the connection is as follow:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True
```

But there is no Database in my SQLEXPRESS Instance, I have checked it with SQL Server Management Studio.

I also cant find anything if I search my filesystem for `*.mdf`.

`App_Data` in my Project is Empty...

But all CRUD operations are working fine, there has to be something.

The only way I can see that table is to connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS` via the Visual Studio Server Explorer. But where is this physically located? Why cant I see the table if I connect to `.\SQLEXPRESS` via SQL Server Management Studio?

Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't specify the `Initial Catalog` in your connection string so probably you are using the `Master` database.

You need to specify the `Initial catalog` like this:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=yourDBName;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. But my master database does not contain any tables.

Comment: @Bgl86...you have to specify the database you want the connection string to connect to so you just need to specify the `Initial catalog` in your connection string and try again.

Comment: I just try to understand what was going on ;) Though there are 3 temp tables in master tempdb, I guess it was going there. I have added Initial Catalog but now I get an exception "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string" But thanks I will have a look whats the problem :)