# SQL Server Object Explorer not showing a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

It's a very small code-first EF6 Project. I added a migration and updated a database successfully. Here's the output:

```
PM> update-database -Verbose
```

> Using StartUp project 'ChattyServer'.
>   Using NuGet project 'ChattyDataModel'.
>   Target database is: 'ChattyDataModel.ChattyContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
>   No pending explicit migrations.
>   Running Seed method.

However, when I open the SQL Server Object Explorer, I can't find my database:
[image: No ChattyDataModel.ChattyContext shown]

**UPD**: The `app.config` - which connection string should I use for `LocalDb`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**UPD**: Updated the `app.config`, added:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnect" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;ConnectTimeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then created a new migration and updated a database. No changes in the SQL Server Object Explorer

**UPD** I changed the directory from master to chatty, created a new migration and updated the db-still can't see db in the SQL Server Object Explorer

Comment: Can you show the connection string you're using?

Comment: @CodeNotFound App.config is up there.

Comment: go to solution explorer -> click-> show all file . then go to App_data check anything there ?

Comment: you stil not set connection string! set , then reapply previous step

Comment: Which connection string should I use for LocalDb?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true; Where do I put it?

Comment: In your webconfig file, close to the top there is a <configSections> tag.  It goes in there.

Comment: I have no webconfig file

Comment: You are using the Master database. Check this post to know how to set your connection string:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982552/cant-find-my-ef-code-first-database/

Comment: @S.Akbari So, I specified Initial Catalog=Chatty; created a new migration and updated a database- still nothing

Comment: @small-j...But you didn't connect to SQLEXPRESS. In your Server Explorer click on *Connect to Database* then in the Server name type `.\sqlexpress` then *Test Connection* then in the *Select or enter a database name* you should get your database.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thanks, right, may I have the answer from you, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Firstly**: You are using the Master database. Check this post to know how to set your connection string: [Cant find my EF code first database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982552/cant-find-my-ef-code-first-database)

**Secondly**:  You didn't connect to `SQLEXPRESS`:

- In your Server Explorer click on Connect to Database.
- Then in the Server name type `.\sqlexpress`
- Then Test Connection.
- then in the Select or enter a database name you should get your
  database.

Comment: I am doing all that, and after selecting a valid db, it doesn't still show up in the Server Explorer tool box

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that I hadn't connected SSOX to the right instance of SQL Server.  I had my older full version connected, not the SQL Express.  The program was functioning perfectly but not on the db I was looking at!

I connected to (my pc)\SQLExpress and voila!  I could see my database!  *slaps forehead*

Hope that helps someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for sql server explorer
2. Right click - then click Add sql Server
3. Click on browse tap
4. local > you can find your server name listed below local.
5. Trust server certificat - True

Then you're good to go :)

Comment: I dont think this is clear, and this does not answer the question. needs clarity, I will recommend deletion as it does not add anything other than confusion