# How to Pass Full Sqlite Connection String to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I am trying to pass the full connection string to `DbContext` constructor as an argument and I get this error:

> Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.

And this is what I have tried:

```
public DatabaseContext() :base(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|ComponentDatabase.sqlite") {}
```

---

Problem can't be about anything else but connection string because I was able to connect my database using connection string from `App.config` like this:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- use AppDomain.SetData to set the DataDirectory -->
    <add name="MapDbConnectionStr" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|ComponentDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" /><add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.105.2" newVersion="1.0.105.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.105.2" newVersion="1.0.105.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**DbContext**

```
public DatabaseContext() :base("MapDbConnectionStr") {}
```

P.S. I know that `App.config` has a lot of unnecessary lines, yes.

Comment: Not sure duplicate but this might helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/35982626/2946329

Comment: Nope, it's about missing initial catalog in config file in MSSQL database, this is about passing actual connection string to constructor in Sqlite. AFAIK Sqlite has no inital catalog option. Even if it has, I still can't find the correct form of the string when passing to constructor directly.

Comment: In case you are working **only** with SQLite database, here is a solution which does not require any configuration files - [EF6, SQLite won't work without App.confg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615926/ef6-sqlite-wont-work-without-app-confg/43688403#43688403)

Comment: @IvanStoev Looks like it can fix my problem, gonna try asap, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware there isn't a Connection factory for the type of database you are trying to connect to.

You could write your own connection factory:

```
public class MySqlLiteConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

now go and find the entry for defaulConnectionfactory in app.config and replace the line which specifies the type. At the moment thats going to read something like this:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

change it to something like this:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MyNamespace.MySQLiteConnectionFactory, MyAssemblyHere" />
```

You should now be able to correctly use the Context ctor (string connectionString).

There is another was of doing this without relying on appsettings EF 6 and onwards supports code-based configuration.

So you can do something with configurations that looks a bit like this:

```
DbConfiguration.Loaded += (_, a) => 
   { 
       a.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>((s, k) => new MyProviderServices(s)); 
       a.ReplaceService<IDbConnectionFactory>((s, k) => new MyConnectionFactory(s)); 
   };
```

Full details of this are documented [here at microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx):

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is there a way to totally avoid depending on app.config? I am trying to pass full connection string because I want to avoid using app.config.

Comment: I think I found it, created a class `SQLiteConfiguration: DbConfiguration` in `DbContext` class, but still I get the same `Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.`

Comment: I have augmented the article which should go some way to helping you achieve your aim.

Comment: Finally solved. Here is how: I used your answer in addition to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615926/ef6-sqlite-wont-work-without-app-confg/43688403#43688403. And deleted connection string and entity framework sections from app.config (this part is necessary otherwise error persists).

Comment: I've added the other post as a favourite Saibot this is useful

Answer (score 3):

Using the name from config file works because it can determine the provider type based on accompanying config provided. When using the connection string directly in the constructor it cannot determine that the connection string is for SQLite and assumes MSSQL so it is trying to use a `SqlConnection`. Hence the error message you encountered.

Take Note:

> The connection to the database (including the name of the database)
>   can be specified in several ways. If the parameterless DbContext
>   constructor is called from a derived context, then the name of the
>   derived context is used to find a connection string in the app.config
>   or web.config file. If no connection string is found, then the name is
>   passed to the DefaultConnectionFactory registered on the Database
>   class. The connection factory then uses the context name as the
>   database name in a default connection string. (This default connection
>   string points to .\SQLEXPRESS on the local machine unless a different
>   DefaultConnectionFactory is registered.) Instead of using the derived
>   context name, the connection/database name can also be specified
>   explicitly by passing the name to one of the DbContext constructors
>   that takes a string. The name can also be passed in the form
>   "name=myname", in which case the name must be found in the config file
>   or an exception will be thrown. Note that the connection found in the
>   app.config or web.config file can be a normal database connection
>   string (not a special Entity Framework connection string) in which
>   case the DbContext will use Code First. However, if the connection
>   found in the config file is a special Entity Framework connection
>   string, then the DbContext will use Database/Model First and the model
>   specified in the connection string will be used. An existing or
>   explicitly created DbConnection can also be used instead of the
>   database/connection name.

[Taken from the class remarks for `DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_5)

The last quoted sentence stands out...

> An existing or explicitly created DbConnection can also be used
>   instead of the database/connection name.

You could consider using `SQLiteConnection`

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext {

    public DatabaseContext() 
        :base(new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|ComponentDatabase.sqlite"), true) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Well, I was asking about passing full connection string, not passing a connection object. When you pass a connection object, entity framework can't take full control of it so it can cause small scale problems in future. I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, but it's not helping.

Answer (score -1):

As i understood correctly it could be helpful, please use builder with db context options. I use SqlServer, hovewer there should be not a lot of changes.

```
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MapDbContext>();
builder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MapDbConnectionStr"].ConnectionString), opt => opt.EnableRetryOnFailure());
var mycontext = new MapDbContext(builder.Options);

public MapDbContext(DbContextOptions<MapDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
```

Hope it helps, Good luck.